# How to share Back to my Mac across different Apple IDs?

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id, remote-control, back-to-my-mac

I'm trying to figure out the best way to remotely get into my family's iMac from my MacBook Pro as needed while I'm away. An internet search taught me that Back to my Mac was the thing, but that only works when the computers are on the same Apple ID, and I've got a different Apple ID from my parents (I know their login information, for what it's worth).

Short of creating a new account on my parents' Apple ID, is there a way to use Back to my Mac to get from my computer to my parents'?

Answer (score 1):

Screen Sharing works across multiple Apple IDs and is probably what you're looking for. So long as someone at home can access your iMac and click "Accept" on the Screen Sharing notification that they will receive, it will allow you to remotely control the iMac and copy files on and off of it.

Comment: I've seen screen sharing offered on locally-connected computers, but how do I set it up remotely?

Comment: Here's a great article on that: http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/10/remote-control-mac-screen-sharing-os-x/